# Correct way to enqueue page specific CSS file

Tags: php, css, wp-enqueue-script

I am looking for an alternate way than using functions.php and applying conditionals based on each page's ID, instead I would like to enqueue the CSS right at the top of each page like this:

```
<?php
defined('ABSPATH') or die();
?>

<?php get_header();?>
<?php wp_enqueue_style('home', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css', '', 1, 'all'); ?>
```

And in the header, its own CSS script like this right before wp_head():

```
...
    <title><?php wp_title();?></title>

    <?php wp_enqueue_style('header', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/header.css', '', 1, 'all'); ?>

    <?php wp_head();?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class();?>>
```

So this way a CSS file would be enqueued in the header.php and then another in that specific page.php. Is this the right approach for someone wishing to add page specific css?

Answer (score 2):

> So this way a CSS file would be enqueued in the header.php and then another in that specific page.php.

No because:

- all the things that get enqueued are processed in the header but you're calling it after the header has already been done. The cat has already gotten out of the bag, the horse has already bolted, the order matters. At best this will push the CSS to the footer instead
- This would add the CSS to every single page

Instead, you're already using `body_class()` and that function is there for a reason, so add the CSS everywhere and use the classes from that function to target just the pages you want. This way you don't need a separate file or weird PHP logic, it just works. E.g. post archives has a `archive` class as well as others, ranging from generic classes such as `post` to `single` to `single-post postid-1067`, as well as other utility classes such as wether the user is logged in, or the specific template file ( `single-post-template` ). These exist for all pages WordPress can serve ( if `body_class` is used ).

A conditional enqueue is neither necessary or optimal here unless the file you're enqueing is especially large.

But if you insist, you can grab the post ID outside the loop and wrap your enqueue in an `if` statement using `$id = get_queried_object_id();`. Note that this can also return user IDs or term IDs if you're on an author archive or a category archive for example, so pay attention to the functions such as `is_singular()` or `is_archive()`

Also, if your styling blocks then use `block.json` to specify the stylesheets and scripts for the frontend. If you do this, WordPress will automatically enqueue those files but only when that block is used.

Comment: Hello Tom. Thanks for your reply. I am a bit confused here now.  You say that 'A conditional enqueue is neither necessary or optimal here ..'.

How else shall I utilize the page classes that you mentioned? Aren't they supposed to be in an `if` conditional to check their existence? Secondly, I want to be able to have header/footer css to be available on every page, so I guess I create a `header_footer.css` and enqueue it in `functions. php` to load on every page?

P.S.: I dont have 15 reputation to up-vote your answer :(

Comment: you don't need to, the browser can do that for you. E.g. `.single-post-template h1 { color: blue; }` makes all headings blue, but only on posts, even if the CSS is loaded everywhere. Instead of relying on PHP or conditional loading, rely instead on classic CSS rules. Those body tag HTML classes are not just for show.

Comment: Interesting way to use `body_class()`. I wasn't aware of it. 
But I guess I am being misunderstood here. `body_class()` is defined in the header.php which will run on every page and will give all the default WP classes to the elements. But I need to have separate CSS files to define different styling for different pages to optimize CSS and load only the necessary CSS for each page. I don't want to have all h1s on my site be of the same color or size etc.

Comment: If I am having an entire CSS file for home page with specific class names that I manually give in the HTML, why would I want it to be loaded on a separate page where I have kept file names different and with different behavior?

Comment: One CSS file can power the entire thing, just because the CSS is loaded everywhere does not mean all the rules apply to all the pages, `h1 { color: blue; }` makes all h1's blue everywhere, but `.postid-1067 h1 { color: blue; }` makes only the heading on the post page with the ID 1067 blue, even if that CSS is present on the homepage

Comment: Also, if you're using the block editor, it's already doing this behind the scenes for you by only loading the styling of blocks that are actually used